# How to replace string, new line and spaces together in python

Tags: python, html

I have a long string called webpage contains something like this:

```
"<!--  \n    <div class=\"section_content\"> \n    </div>\n\n-->  "
```

I want to replace the comments symbol `"<!--"` and `"-->"` with spaces. 
However I cannot directly replace them, since there are other real comments, like `"<!-- comments -->"`, in the long string.

I was trying to use

```
re.sub(r"<!--\s+\n\s+<div",r"\n<div",webpage,flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

But it does not work at all. Can someone help? 
The result should be `"\n    <div class=\"section_content\"> \n    </div>\n\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
import re

regex = r"<!--(\s*\n\s*<div[^>]*>\s*\n\s*</div>\n\n)-->"
string = "<!--  \n    <div class=\"section_content\"> \n    </div>\n\n-->  "
res = re.sub(regex, r"\1", string)
print res
```

Result:

```
"  \n    <div class=\"section_content\"> \n    </div>\n\n"
```

Then, if you don't want newlines and spaces at the ends of the string you can use the `.strip()` method of the string object.